# Symfony 2 - FOSUserBundle - Create and Persist another entity inside the constructor of User class

Tags: php, symfony, constructor, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I'm making a website where users can create albums.
I would like to create a default album per user.

I would like to create an Album entity and to persist it in the constructor of my User class.

Is it possible ? 
I just know that the entityManager is not accessible from an Entity... That's why it's a problem for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though this technically IS possible I would strongly recommend you not to do this.

To answer your question, it is possible and it would be done like this:

```
class User extends FOSUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Album", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $albums;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->albums = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->addAlbum(new Album());
    }

    public function addAlbum(Album $album)
    {
        $this->albums[] = $album;
    }

    public function getAlbums()
    {
        return $this->albums:
    }
}
```

With setup like this whenever you create a new user and save it, a related album will be created together with it. I have to repeat, **even though it's possible, don't do it like this**.

### Good solutions

There are few strategies that can be used to achieve what you want.

#### FOSUserBundle master

If you're not using 1.3.x version of FOSUserBundle but master, you can see that [RegistrationController](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/RegistrationController.php#L32) fires a few events. The one you're interested in is `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE`. You should [create an event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) and add album to user in your listener.

#### FOSUserBundle 1.3.x

If you're using one of older versions, these events don't exist unfortunately and you can do it two ways.

1. [Extend FOSUserBundle UserManager and override `createUser` method](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.3.x/Resources/doc/user_manager.md#overriding-the-user-manager). You can add your album adding logic there. I would prefer this approach.
2. Override FOSUserBundle RegistrationController::registerAction. It can be viable option sometimes but in your case I think option 1 is better.

Comment: I'm trying the good solution. I guess that I still need to put the default property in User Class right ? And I will set it in event listener call back I guess?

Comment: For good solutions User Class stays the same except the `$this->addAlbum(new Album())` line. Remove it.